# Querying a specific database for tables in a specific schema that were created more than 30 days ago?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to query DatabaseA for tables that were created over thirty days ago in SchemaC. I have managed to cobble together two separate queries; one that finds all tables that were created in SchemaC:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'SchemaC'
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
```

And one that finds all tables within the database that were created over 30 days ago:

```
SELECT [name] AS [DatabaseA], [create_date] AS [CreatedDate] FROM sys.tables
WHERE [create_date] < DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
```

I can compare the results and get the information I need, but I am sure that my lack of expertise is preventing me from finding the single query that returns all the information I want. Am I going about this incorrectly and there is a more effective method?

Answer (score 1):

You can join the two tables together and add an `AND` like so

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
INNER JOIN sys.tables st ON t.table_name = st.name
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'SchemaC'
AND [create_date] < DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: Careful. The INFORMATION_SCHEMA views should not be used to determine the schema of an object. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186224.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach going directly to sys.objects. The INFORMATION_SCHEMA objects are around for backwards compatibility. They should generally be avoided.

- [The case against INFORMATION_SCHEMA views](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views)

  ```
  select * 
  from sys.objects
  where SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) = 'SchemaC'
  and create_date < DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())
  and type = 'U' --user Table
  ```